# Why are my carrots white?

Tags: carrots

I planted Early Nantes V earlier in the year and am just starting to harvest them.  Some are orange but some are white.  Why is this?

Comment: When you get the reputation, a picture would help a great deal here.

Answer (score 2):

Did you buy the seeds? My best guess would be that there were some white carrot seeds mixed in by accident. If you save your own seed, I'd suspect cross pollination.

Answer (score 1):

White carrots are a result of cross pollination with their native cousin Queen Anne's Lace.  If you are saving carrot seed yourself you have to isolate the plants as Queen Anne's Lace is a widespread (and very beneficial) wild plant (some may say weed).  If this was seed you bought, I would not hesitate to report the issue and the batch/lot information off the seed packet.  A reputable seed seller should take action on the issue.